# Images won't align with center of project

Tags: html, css, centering

I am working on setting up my website - it still has a long way to go, and I'm new at this. I have a page with a series of clickable boxes representing my portfolio. However, the images I want to be displayed in these boxes are orienting themselves to the left rather than the center of the box. Any advice?

Website where problem is: http://corey-dickinson.com/portfolio.html

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>CoreyDickinson.com</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800|Playfair+Display:,300, 400, 700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@4.2.7/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- Theme Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAq6urACkpKQD19fUA4ODgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACEwAAADEgAAIhMAADEiAAASITADEiEAAEIiEzEiJAAAMiIhEiIjAAABIiIiIhAAAAQiIiIiQAAAAyIiIiIwAAAAEiIiIQAAAABCIiIkAAAAADIiIiMAAAAAASIiEAAAAAAEIiJAAAAAAAMiIjAAAAAAABIhAAAAAAAAQiQAAADH4wAAw8MAAMGDAADAAwAAwAMAAOAHAADgBwAA4AcAAPAPAADwDwAA8A8AAPgfAAD4HwAA+B8AAPw/AAD8PwAA" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="site-wrap">

      <a href="#" class="offcanvas-toggle js-offcanvas-toggle">Menu</a>
      <div class="offcanvas_menu" id="offcanvas_menu">
        <ul class="mb-5">
          <li><a href="index.html">Bio</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social">
          <li><a href="cdickinson01742@gmail.com" class="fa fa-at"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/corey.dickinson" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/corey-dickinson/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
        </ul>

</br><!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a> and coded in Brackets by CD
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->

      </div>
         <a href="index.html" class="home-button w3-padding-large"><px-2 class="fa fa-home"></a>
          <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            </div>

            <hr><hr>
            <div class = "container">
          <ul class="portfolio-list">
            <li>
              <a href="https://redcross.carto.com/viz/3ea45828-7769-4f92-9170-bec6c63dfc9a/public_map">
                <img src="img/arcban2.jpg" alt="" style="image-orientation: center">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Diaspora Mapping RC</h3>
                  <span>A project for the Red Cross that designed maps of the distribution of selected diaspora populations across the United States. The map was used by large numbers of volunteers to coordinate outreach programs.</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="index_search.html">
                <img src="img/qcwide.png" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Quiet Contractors Directory</h3>
                  <span>Project for small non-profit focused on noise polution to create a directory/webmap of environmentally friendly contractors across the US.</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="MukigavMutooroMap-July2017.pdf">
                <img src="img/kasiisibanner2.png" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Tribal Map Western Uganda</h3>
                  <span>A map produced for the Kasiisi project, a small NGO in Uganda. This map outlines the spatial patterns in different tribes in the region. This data was derived from a survey I oversaw that was distributed using XML forms in ODK. </span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7Cuy5AO88Y">
                <img src="img/TED_banner-resized.png" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>TED Talk Nauru</h3>
                  <span>A TED talk outlining the results and reflections from a project I created. The project was focused on mapping the environmental degredation on Nauru, a small island nation in the South Pacific.</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="A)%20Report_Living_Situation_Refugee_Camps_2017.pdf">
                <img src="img/UNHCR_banner2.png" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Refugee Camp Report</h3>
                  <span>An analysis of quality of life patterns in Syrian refugee camps, developed for a class at Clark University. The results of this project were submitted to UNHCR.</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
             <li>
              <a href="Cape_Cod_Sand.mp4">
                <img src="img/nps-banner-2.png" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>Analysis of changing seashore patterns</h3>
                  <span> Analyzed the effects of sea level rise on Nauset Spit for the North Atlantic Coastal Lab for Cape Cod National Seashore. The project involved exstensive research of historical maps and arial imagary.</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

             <div class = "container">
        <h1 class="mb-5"><a href="GISPortfolioCDICKINSON_V2.zip">Download Zip</a></h1>
        </div>

    <!-- loader -->
    <div id="loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#f4b214"/></svg></div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope to help, Please try `.portfolio-list li a{text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for the  tag like so

```
<img class="center_img" ..... />
```

and then in your css have:

```
img.center_img{
    margin: y_margin_values auto;
}
```

Setting two values for `margin` sets first value as top and bottom, second as left and right. Setting the left and right values to `auto` will center the `<img>` within its container. If that still doesn't work, set it's parent `<a>` or parent `<li>' to have`width: 100% ' or whatever width you desire.

Comment: it will work only display type is block /table/ flex/ table etc. not with default display type of image that is inline.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible way to get the desired result. lets discuss few of them

**Pulling the Image in center**

Here we will just pull the image to center, although image size will be the same as it is now. so your `li` width is full width, but image will be in center may be if size(width) of image if less.

apply the below css to the image inside your `li`

```
.portfolio-list li a img
{
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

**setting image as background to your li > a**

And another when you want the size of the image same as your `li` its better to set the image as background rather than showing it as html element inside your `li`.

So you can apply the below css, make it sure we need to set the `background-image` separately for each of your `li`. and can remove the `img` element side your `li a`.

```
.portfolio-list li a
{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 230px;
}

.portfolio-list li a.first
{
  background-image: url('http://corey-dickinson.com/img/arcban2.jpg');
}

.portfolio-list li a.second
{
  background-image: url('http://corey-dickinson.com/img/qcwide.png');
}
...
...
//And so on for other li.
```

Comment: hey! I've tried the second method and it did not work. Do I need to tag each li item as first and second and so forth?

Comment: right... actually you have to apply the class on each `a` tag like `first OR second OR third` we are doing so we can apply the individual background image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.portfolio-list li a {
    text-align: center;
}
```